# sql select in string with a split function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

how can i make a select from not normed table.

i have the table like this:

[image]

this table is not norme BNF 2.

i just want to select the NO_ID where DEPARTEMENT = something.
example:
when the input 44 then NO_ID =1 
when the input 37 then NO_ID =3
when the input 13(not in table) then NO_ID = 5

of course when input = 44 it works:

```
SELECT [NO_ID]    
FROM [T_TARIF_ZONE]
WHERE DEPARTEMENT = '44'
```

but how can i put in WHERE statement when the input = 37 or 13.

thanks you in advance,
Stev

Comment: I think you need to get NO_ID values where DEPARTMENT number exists in DEPARTMENT number string?

Comment: On what basis NO_ID 5 is selected for input 13?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT [NO_ID]    
FROM [T_TARIF_ZONE]
WHERE DEPARTEMENT like '%37%'
```

Comment: thanks you, yes you right, but how can i retrun 5 when the value is not in Departement example 13

Comment: This would fail if there is a '371' code in there - I don't know if that applies here.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select 
    NO_ID, 
    DEPARTMEMT 
from 
    T
where 
    ' '+DEPARTMEMT+' ' like 
    (case when @var=13 then ' FRANCE ' ELSE '% '+@var+' %' END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle version -

```
SELECT [NO_ID]    
FROM [T_TARIF_ZONE]
WHERE INSTR(DEPARTEMENT, '44')>0  OR INSTR(DEPARTEMENT, '37')>0 OR INSTR(DEPARTEMENT, '13')>0
```

SQL Server version -

```
    SELECT [NO_ID]    
FROM [T_TARIF_ZONE]
WHERE PATINDEX('44', DEPARTEMENT)>0  OR PATINDEX('37', DEPARTEMENT)>0 OR PATINDEX('13', DEPARTEMENT)>0
```